# Restoring SQL Server 2012 DB - OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE NAME Not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, restore

Database Admins, can you please help me out and let me know why my script is not allowing me to `DECRYPTBYKEY` once I restore my DB from a PRODUCTION BACKUP....

```
-- SET Staging to Single User Mode to be able to RESTORE DB---
-- STEP 1 (Works No Problems Here)
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE Staging
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

RESTORE DATABASE Staging
   FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\MyDBRestore.bak' ;
GO

-- STEP 2 - USE ONLY IF THE ABOVE IS UNSUCCESSFUL ||| FAILURE ****** RESTORE RUN THE FOLLOWING SCRIPT -----
--If the above is successful the DB sets itself back to MULTI_USER

--ALTER DATABASE Staging
--SET MULTI_USER;
--GO

--ALTER DATABASE Staging
--SET READ_WRITE 
--GO


-- STEP 3 (Works No Problems Here)
--------------- @@@@@@@@@@@@@@ IMPORTANT UNCOMMIT AND RUN @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ MANUAL STEPS ----------------------
-- RBD - Recreate Security ID'S AND PERMISSIONS FOR Stored Procedure EXECUTE RIGHTS, because PASSWORDS are different on lower
-- environments

--USE [Staging]
--GO

--/****** Object:  User [WebUser]    Script Date: 4/13/2015 11:15:51 AM ******/
--DROP USER [WebUser]
--GO

--/****** Object:  User [WebUser]    Script Date: 4/13/2015 11:15:51 AM ******/
--CREATE USER [IUser] FOR LOGIN [IUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
--GO

--USE [Staging]
--GO

--/****** Object:  User [Management]    Script Date: 4/13/2015 11:16:37 AM ******/
--DROP USER [Management]
--GO

--/****** Object:  User [Management]    Script Date: 4/13/2015 11:16:37 AM ******/
--CREATE USER [Management] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
--GO

--USE [Staging]
--GO

--/****** Object:  User [Transfer_Admin]    Script Date: 4/13/2015 11:19:42 AM ******/
--DROP USER [Transfer_Admin]
--GO

--/****** Object:  User [Transfer_Admin]    Script Date: 4/13/2015 11:19:42 AM ******/
--CREATE USER [Transfer_Admin] FOR LOGIN [Transfer_Admin] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
--GO



--Grants Execute Rights to Staging
--USE [Staging]
--GO
--GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [WebUser]
--GO

--USE [Staging]
--GO
--GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [Transfer_Admin]
--GO


--------------- @@@@@@@@@@@@@@ IMPORTANT RESET KEYS BECAUSE YOU HAVE MOVED TO A NEW SERVER @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ----------------------

-- Apply Scripts for SECURITY ONLY AFTER SUCCESSESFUL RESTORE, I REPEAT ONLY AFTER SUCCESSFUL RESTORE.
--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@MIGHT NOT HAVE TO RUN THESE SCRIPTS @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
USE [Staging]
RESTORE SERVICE MASTER KEY FROM FILE = 'C:\!IMPORTANT KEYS\SQL Encryption\SQLServiceMasterKey' 
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'DEMO_PASSWORD_SERVICE_MASTER' --[FORCE] --- Currently not using force because the script will run


OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'DEMO_PASSWORD_MASTER'
--ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY
GO


USE [Staging]

IF (select Count(*) from sys.symmetric_keys where name like '%SKey%') > 0
BEGIN
    DROP SYMMETRIC KEY SKey
END

IF (select Count(certificate_id) from sys.certificates where name = 'MCer') > 0
BEGIN
    DROP CERTIFICATE MCer
END

DROP MASTER KEY;

Create Master Key Encryption by Password='DEMO_PASSWORD_MASTER'


create certificate MCer
 from file = N'C:\!IMPORTANT KEYS\SQL Encryption\SQLCert'
 with private key
  ( file = N'C:\!IMPORTANT KEYS\SQL Encryption\SQLCertPrivateKey'
  , decryption by password = N'DEMO_PASSWORD_MCER'
   );

   Create Symmetric Key SKey With Algorithm=AES_256 encryption by Certificate MCer



--GRANT RIGHTS TO WebUser for Certificates Permissions
USE Staging;


--GRANT RIGHTS TO WebUser for Symmetric Key Permissions
GRANT CONTROL ON CERTIFICATE::MCer TO WebUser;
GO
GRANT CONTROL ON SYMMETRIC KEY:: SKey TO [WebUser]
GO


-- Uncomment for testing to ensure the encryption was applied correctly
--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$


--!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  THIS DOES NOT WORK AFTER THE DB RESTORE AND RUNNING ALL THESE SCRIPTS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$


OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MCer
SELECT CONVERT([varchar](MAX), DECRYPTBYKEY(PasswordEncrypt)) AS 'UnEncryptedPWD' FROM Users WHERE [User_ID] = 1
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SKey



OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MCer
SELECT CONVERT([varchar](MAX), DECRYPTBYKEY(PasswordEncrypt)) AS 'UnEncryptedPWD' FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE [AccountID] = 1
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SKey
```

**UPDATE ON THIS RESTORE ISSUE**

I had an old DB GURU friend provide a script and instead of all this code all I had to run to restore the DB was as follows, but I still think I had to have the KEYS CORRECT.  ALL IS WORKING ----

```
-- SET Staging to Single User Mode to be able to RESTORE DB---
-- STEP 1 (Works No Problems Here)
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE Staging
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

RESTORE DATABASE Staging
   FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\MyDBRestore.bak' ;
GO
```

DB GURU CODE THAT REALIGNS IDs

```
DECLARE 
 @username varchar(25)

DECLARE fixusers CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
 SELECT UserName = [name] FROM sysusers
 WHERE issqluser = 1 AND (sid IS NOT NULL AND sid <> 0x0)
 and suser_sname(sid) IS NULL
 ORDER BY [name]

OPEN fixusers
FETCH FROM fixusers INTO @username
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
   EXEC sp_change_users_login 'update_one', @username, @username
   END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
       PRINT 'User ' + @username + ' is a schema, windows login, or a SQL login that does not exist at the instance level.  Moving on to next user.'
     END CATCH
   FETCH NEXT FROM fixusers INTO @username
 END

CLOSE fixusers
DEALLOCATE fixusers

PRINT 'Remapping complete.'
```

Comment: Can you post the error message as well ?

Comment: There is not an error message, everything is running fine, however when I go to DECYPTBYKEY I am getting NULL results.   I am banging my head on the desk.  I really need to be able to restore the PROD DB to lower environments and get the Encryption working.

Comment: Also, please beware I scrubbed USERID(s) and PASSWORD(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you're dropping the current symmetric key (why?) and creating a new one.

When the new one is created, since you're not using KEY_SOURCE, IDENTITY_VALUE, and only supplying the same ALGORITHM you're going to get a different symmetric key each time. If you want the data to be the same, use the same values for ALL of those inputs (which is why you're getting a null).

I also don't know why you're dropping the current symmetric key as that's what is encrypting your data.

Update (Example):

```
CREATE DATABASE EncryptionRestoreTestProd;
GO

USE EncryptionRestoreTestProd;
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE name = '##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##')
BEGIN
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '$trongP@ss';
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.certificates WHERE name = 'MiddleEncryptionCert')
BEGIN
    CREATE CERTIFICATE MiddleencryptionCert
    WITH SUBJECT = 'Cert used to protect other encryption keys.';
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE name = 'SuperSecretKey')
BEGIN
    CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SupersecretKey
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MiddleEncryptionCert
END

CREATE TABLE MyEncryptedInfo
(
ID  INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
SuperSecretInfo VARBINARY(8000) NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertAndEncryptData @SensitiveData VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SuperSecretKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MiddleEncryptionCert;
    INSERT INTO MyEncryptedInfo VALUES(ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('SuperSecretKey'), @SensitiveData, 0, null));
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SuperSecretKey;
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE GetDecryptedData
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SuperSecretKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MiddleEncryptionCert;
    SELECT ID, CAST(DECRYPTBYKEY(SuperSecretInfo) AS VARCHAR(4000)) AS SuperSecretDecryptedInfo FROM MyEncryptedInfo;
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SuperSecretKey;
END
GO

EXEC InsertAndEncryptData 'Super Secret Info, SHHHHHHH Do Not Tell!';
GO

SELECT * FROM MyEncryptedInfo;
GO

EXEC GetDecryptedData;
GO

BACKUP DATABASE EncryptionRestoreTestProd TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\EncryptionProd.bak' WITH COMPRESSION, CHECKSUM, INIT, STATS=10;
GO

RESTORE DATABASE EncryptionRestoreTestDev FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\EncryptionProd.bak' 
WITH MOVE N'EncryptionRestoreTestProd' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\EncryptionRestoreTestDev.mdf',  
MOVE N'EncryptionRestoreTestProd_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\EncryptionRestoreTestDev_log.ldf', 
CHECKSUM, STATS=10;
GO

USE EncryptionRestoreTestDev;
GO

-- simulate a change of SMK by dropping and regenerating

ALTER MASTER KEY DROP ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY;
GO

SELECT name, is_master_key_encrypted_by_server FROM sys.databases WHERE name like 'Encryption%';
GO

USE master;
GO

select name, create_date, modify_date, key_guid FROM sys.symmetric_keys where name = '##MS_ServiceMasterKey##';
-- ##MS_ServiceMasterKey##  2014-10-29 14:32:25.893 2014-10-29 14:32:25.893 FD3E2F7C-E9CB-4E4C-95DD-D2C05F75A8CC
-- ##MS_ServiceMasterKey##  2014-10-29 14:32:25.893 2015-04-20 12:55:24.773 DDCB0600-199E-4C7B-BDC1-AFD727D143FB
ALTER SERVICE MASTER KEY REGENERATE;

select name, create_date, modify_date, key_guid FROM sys.symmetric_keys where name = '##MS_ServiceMasterKey##';
GO

USE EncryptionRestoreTestDev;
GO
-- Shoudl fail because we removed the SMK transparent decryption
EXEC GetDecryptedData;
GO

-- Fix without creating new keys
-- The chain is now broken because the DMK can't be opened automagically
-- Lets fix that
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '$trongP@ss'
GO

ALTER MASTER KEY DROP ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY;
GO

ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY;
GO

CLOSE MASTER KEY;
GO

-- now try
EXEC GetDecryptedData;
GO
```

Comment: The problem was with Remapping the IDs back to the Database After the restore and I also did not have Identical Master DB Keys Across the different servers and databases.  I am no longer dropping the Symmetric Key.  All I am running is what is listed after the UDPATE above in the first post.

Comment: The problem is not with your orphaned users (which is what the script fixes). In the updated, you're just restoring the database - correct? If so, you'll need to open the database master key (`OPEN MASTER KEY`) and add decryption by the service master key (if you want transparent key decryption) which can be done through `ALTER MASTER KEY`. If you wanted to test, you could open the database master key through the password, then open the certificate, then open the symmetric key and in the same session decrypt your data.

Comment: Sean, I will come back to this discussion.  I have bookmarked for now, I will let you know the results, but I am under timelines on another project with a third party API.  You know how that goes.

Comment: No worries, I've updated my answer with an example.